# Setting Repo with Puppet for Debian

Tags: puppet, apt

I am trying to just set a repo in Ubuntu that is not centrally managed repo. In the past I worked on CentOS at work and would just use the yumrepo resource definition to do this. But, now I'm in an Ubuntu shop and that won't work. The Puppet docs say I need to use dpkg to do this, but I cannot find anything in the docs over dpkg, only yumrepo. I'm a tad confused and would appreciate someone clearing this up. Seems like it shouldn't be hard and it also seems like something I shouldn't have to install a third party module for, but that's the only solution I've seen people recommending online and that's just not an option for me. Thanks.

Comment: And after more testing dpkg isn't even resource that exits. Confusion level maxed out. I have to be missing something simple because this is a simple thing to do and yet I'm baffled how to do this with apt.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the link to Puppet docs that say you should use dpkg.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet has a supported module [puppetlabs/apt](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt) that you should use on Ubuntu Linux. Also, as [noted](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/type.html#puppet-60-type-changes) in the Puppet 6 release notes, the `yumrepo` type has also moved to an external module now, which has resolved the inconsistency you alluded to in the way Red Hat was previously treated as more of a first-class citizen in the Puppet ecosystem, which was never really the intention.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a Debian repository using the apt class pointing to any server you want, local or remote:

```
apt::source {
    "$lsbdistcodename":
        include_src => false,
        location    => "http://10.0.0.8/debian/$lsbdistcodename",
        repos       => "main contrib non-free",
    ;
}
```